# How to send Dialogflow an access token from Swift using ApiAi Pod

Tags: ios, swift, dialogflow-es, access-token

While following this tutorial: https://medium.com/@pallavtrivedi03/integrating-dialogflow-as-a-chat-bot-in-an-ios-app-e66a4c7f2723
I was unable to find out how to interact with dialogflow intents that require authentication via the swift app. Once the dialogflow path reaches a point where it needs authentication, the request is not met with a response.

I have successfully sent requests and received responses from dialogflow using the following:

```
    func performQuery(senderId:String,name:String,text:String)
    {
        let request = ApiAI.shared().textRequest()
        if text != "" {
            request?.query = text
        } else {
            return
        }



        //print("request: ")
        request?.setMappedCompletionBlockSuccess({ (request, response) in
            let response = response as! AIResponse
            print(response.result.parameters)
            //print(response.result.action)
```

I am not an experienced swift user so it could be that I am missing something simple, however, I am unable to find any documentation on the topic.

Any information on ways to interact with dialogflow using oauth2 would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There seems to be some info on the [GitHub README](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-apple-client) on how to set the access token.

Comment: https://www.appcoda.com/chatbot-dialogflow-ios/